# Is it possible to use 2 Mac minis to do a distributed computing system

Tags: macos, mac, graphics-card, distributed-computing

I need some advice on connecting and using 2 Mac minis as a distributed computing system. The situation is that, my current Mac mini went bad on discrete graphics card and is almost usable only in single user mode via Terminal. It is a shame to let go on it, so thinking on re-purpose it, by connected it, somehow to a new Mac mini and use them as grid computers from a single set of monitor-keyboard-mouse. Need to mention that I do not own the second Mac mini yet. I'm thinking on buying it, only if I can make use it together with the crippled on graphics card Mac mini.
Is this possible to achieve this and how? A step by step guide, if anyone can possible come up with will be great. Thank you all in advance for your answers or ideas on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use them to build a 2 node Beowulf cluster using the MPI Cluster tools.

Here's where to get started:
http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/

This also gives some help:
https://www.linux.com/blog/building-beowulf-cluster-just-13-steps

Keep in mind that cluster or grid computing isn't exactly as running a program on a normal 1 processor computer. You will need programs that can harness the power of the 2 computers and share parts of the workload to each nodes (computers) in the cluster for it to work as intended. It won't act like 1 cpu with 4 + 4 cores = 8 cores.

Comment: Your answer and shared links was very informative. Didn`t match my expectations for 1 cpu out of two minis, but still is a solid answer.